# group_names|intersect use of the intersect command

Tags: ansible

```
- debug:
    msg: "welcome"
  when: group_names|intersect(['PEGAALL', 'MDMALL'])
```

Can you please tell me the use of *intersect* function I have already tried to the group_names|intersect command but I don't know the use.

Answer (score 0):

[intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) is a filter (see [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))):

> *"to get a unique list of all items in both lists"*

For example with the inventory

```
[test_jails]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[PEGAALL]
test_02
```

The playbook

```
- hosts: test_jails
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ group_names|intersect(['PEGAALL', 'MDMALL']) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "welcome"
      when: group_names|intersect(['PEGAALL', 'MDMALL'])
```

gives

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": [
        "PEGAALL"
    ]
}


ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "welcome"
}
```

---

- See [Special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `"group_names: List of groups the current host is part of."`
- For the hosts `test_01` and `test_03` there is no *intersect*. The result is an empty list that evaluates to `False` in the *when* condition.
- For the host `test_02` the *intersect* is the list with one item; the name of the group `PEGAALL` that evaluates to `True` in the *when* condition.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply . can you please explain briefly please i am not understand to the group_name|intersect exactly